# When should I use generic parameters in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I got this Typescript example from this [tutorial](https://learntypescript.dev/06/l7-generic-parameter-constraints)

```js
interface Logable {
  log: () => void;
}
function logItems<T extends Logable>(items: T[]): void {
  items.forEach(item => item.log());
}
```

And I'd like to know if, in this case, there's any difference between using the generic constraint or just using `logItems(items: Logable[])`

It seems like, if you don't need a more complex constraint, it's simpler to just specify the type of the parameter.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in thinking that it does not really make a difference. In a broader sense, as long as you are not using generics to model relations between parameters or for the return type, you might *not* need the generic type in the first place.

But there is a *subtle* difference. If we use the generic function, it is perfectly fine to pass an array of objects of any shape as long as the constraint is fulfilled.

```
function logItems<T extends Logable>(items: T[]): void {
  items.forEach(item => item.log());
}

logItems([
  { log: () => {} },
  { a: "123", log: () => {} }
])
```

Extra properties are *allowed* in this case.

Something different happens when we don't use a generic type.

```
function logItems2(items: Logable[]): void {}

logItems2([
  { log: () => {} },
  { a: "123", log: () => {} }
//  ^^^^^^^^ Error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'a' does not exist in type 'Logable'
])
```

Since there are extra checks for *excess properties* when you pass an *object literal* to the function, there is a compiler error.

But you could still pass the array as a variable to the function.

```
const arr = [
  { log: () => {} },
  { a: "123", log: () => {} }
]

logItems2(arr)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDIHsDmcBGAbFAbwChlk8sAuZACgEpkBeAPmQDd1gATAbmIF9iMAK4gEYYOhDksASUgBbAM4AeACrIIAD0gguStFlwFmNYIqXU1AbQC6dah27ISZcxGUA6GOigBRRAALM0UmVncFTwpMejo+QWJo+Q8lGmtSFxlManowl35kfgAaDMJkOGoAIgBGACYAZkqirJyGFnzC4ntiHpExCSks5OVakJTqDGx8CDsHdk4ufJ6ki1H0sjLo1rzCAuLS8qq6xuat2jbWXc7unoQpJTByqCgmZHXMs9z2q-2Nw+Qag0mi1zjs9l1lnJVjQ4M86EA)

Comment: I didn't know that such restrinction existed for object literals, and somehow, it doesn't sounf right to me, but it's good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When the the arguments or the return type depends on a type.

And in the case of that example, you are right, the generic parameter is not required.

---

A better example:

```
function logKey<T>(obj: T, key: keyof T) {
    console.log(obj[key])
}

logKey({ abc: 123 }, 'abc')
```

Here you cannot know what keys are allowed until you supply the object with some keys. In this case the type of the second argument depends on the type of the first.

---

Or:

```
function getFoo<T extends { foo: unknown }>(obj: T): T['foo'] {
    return obj.foo 
}

getFoo({ foo: 'a string' }) // string
getFoo({ foo: 123 }) // number
```

Here the return is different depending on the argument you supplied. In this case the return type depends on the type of the first argument.

---

If no type depends on any other type in your function, then your function does not need to be generic.

Comment: great example, I would have (reduntantly) written it like getFoo2 in this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQGJzgHgCqKoAeUqYAJgM6IDeiw2AXIuANZhwDuSAvgHwAKOACMAVszwBKCQG0A5AzhyAurQCwAKETbEAJ3QhdSEaIB0ixJp6bNaTNgF1FzOQENElKLphhkcxDySiAD0wR5ePsg2GnZYcI70TIgAjABMAMwBQaGIYCAAtsKoutGgkLAIKOhxqfiEJGRUtIlwzBgBADSI7cSkFNRsHNyCJhLS3epaOvpQhsZi5tiWGtYattXYqQnOiG7h3r7+gSFhngdRMRtwW05JaZnHOXmFxdFAA), but it doesn't seem to work. Any idea why?

Comment: When you have more generic parameters than is required, bad things happen. I suspect something circular is going on and typescript bails out and accepts the default provided by the constraint. Generic parameters are _not type variables for you to assign as you wish. Each one should reflect a unique type. And in this case since `F` could be trivially derived from `T`, you can save the compiler a lot of headache. To force `F` to be derived from `T` you could do this https://tsplay.dev/N7y5EW, but that's a bad idea since you still have more generic parameters than you need.

Comment: I guess it should be ok but I'm needlessly confussing the compiler. btw, this thing gets hairy pretty quicly, I'm gonna read about `infer` and the ternary operator in ts, thanks!